# bin width according to custom function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to bin my data in a non-uniform way.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fun(x):
  return >some function of x<
```

What I want now is to make somehing looking like:

```
np.linespace(0.,200.,fun(x))
```

Is there a convenient way to use a numpy function that can handle it?
I just saw that `np.arange` and `np.linspace` work with numbers and cannot take functions as arguments.

I can write a function that can take care of it, but a native solution would be much better.

Comment: write a function? Surely if you write the function, you've done the work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a range of x-values, define your custom function, then call your function on each of the array elements. Numpy makes this quite easy:

```
fun = lambda x: x**2 # Example function
N = 10 # Number of data points
x = np.linspace(0., 200., N) # Creates an array of N points
bins = fun(x) # Applies fun to all values in array x
```

Comment: +1, but I'd say you will normally go with `bins = np.linspace(0, 200, n)**2`, without explicitly declaring a function

Comment: @Jaime Yes, but the x**2 was just an example, perhaps the OP has a more complex function -- it was asked how to do the binning with a function

Comment: Yes, your answer is perfect for the question asked. My comment was more of a general remark on how I would implement it.